# How to list and delete all the resources in a specific AWS region from the UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created some resources in a AWS region which I no longer need. I would like to know:

- Is there a way to list all the resources in a specific AWS region using the UI?
- How to delete all the resources? I presume I have to open each resources individually and delete them one by one?

Comment: You can't do this from aws console. But [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) can be helpful in identifying and deleting your all resources.

Comment: at the least is there a reliable way to list all resources from the UI for a specific region?

Comment: Sadly there is no such way. The closest I can think if is to use inventory in AWS Config, but it also does not [support all resoruces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/resource-config-reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

To delete all resources in a specific region you can use cloud-nuke
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke

To list all resources in one or multiple regions check Aws Tag Editor, in the console filters select All services and in Tag Filter left blank to get all resources
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/tag-editor.html